# RSS Feed template for facebook

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, rss

I want to build a custom template for Facebook based on RSS Feeds, I tried something, but it seems to not work at all since I discovered how to create RSS flux using PHP.

Here is my code :

```
    <?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>
    <?= "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>\n" ?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <title>MonFinancier - Articles</title>
    <link><?= site_url() ?></link>
    <description>MonFinancier.com | Articles</description>
    <language>fr-FR</language>

    <atom:link href="<?= site_url('rss/facebook.xml') ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />

    <?php foreach($articles as $article):?>

    <item>
        <title><![CDATA[<?php echo $article['titre'];?>]]></title>
        <link><?php echo $article['url'];?></link>
        <content :encoded>
            <![CDATA[               
                <!doctype html>
                <html lang="en" prefix="op: http://media.facebook.com/op#">
                  <head>
                    <link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo $article['url'];?>">
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta property="op:version" content="v1.0">
                    <meta property="fb:article_style">
                    <time class="op-published" datetime="<?php echo $article['date_dernier_envoi']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['date_dernier_envoi']; ?></time>
                    <time class="op-modified" datetime="<?php echo $article['date_dernier_envoi']; ?>"> <?php echo $article['date_dernier_envoi']; ?> </time>
                  </head>
                    <body>
                      <article>
                      <header>

                        <title><?php echo $article['titre']; ?><title>
                        <author>
                            <a rel="facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/MonFinancier">MonFinancier</a>
                        </author>

                        <figure>
                            <img src="<?php echo $article['image']; ?>" >
                        </figure>   

                        <h3 class="op-kicker">
                        </h3>

                      </header>

                      <p><?php echo $article['texte']; ?></p> 

                      <figure class="op-ad">
                      </figure>

                      <figure class="op-tracker">
                          <iframe src="" hidden></iframe>
                      </figure>

                      <footer>
                        <!-- Credits for your article -->
                        <aside></aside>

                        <!-- Copyright details for your article -->
                        <small>Copyright (C) <?php echo date('Y') ?> MonFinancier</small>
                      </footer>
                    </article>
                  </body>
                </html>
            ]]>
        </content>
        <guid><?php echo $article['url'];?></guid>
        <category><![CDATA[<?php echo $article['rubrique'];?>]]></category>
    </item>     
    <?php endforeach;?>     
</channel>
```

Comment: "It doesn't work at all" isn't much to go on. What doesn't work? Does it produce incorrect output? an error?